# Swift 3.0 and Alamofire post array

Tags: swift, alamofire

In swift 3.0,  I am using alamofire to send parameters to my backend server. Here is my sample parameters that I used to send:

```
let params:[String: Any] = ["isUrgent": "1",
                                "bestTime": "Morning",
                                "requestType": "1",
                                "api_key": "12345678",
                                "userId": "37",
                                "endTime": "1492757638",
                                "startTime": "1492671236",
                                "title": "Aa",
                                "requestRequirement":
                                    ["state": "",
                                     "city": "",
                                     "isStaffNeeded": "1",
                                     "street": "",
                                     "lat": "",
                                     "staffSkills":
                                        [
                                            ["subSkills":
                                                ["0": "1", "1": "4", "2": "8"],
                                             "masterSkillId": "1"
                                            ],
                                            ["subSkills":
                                                [
                                                    "0": "13",
                                                    "1": "17"
                                                ],
                                             "masterSkillId": "3"
                                            ]
                                        ],
                                     "lng": "",
                                     "venueTypes": [],
                                     "venueTypeName": "",
                                     "isVenueNeeded": "0",
                                     "locationType": "1",
                                     "zipCode": "",
                                     "country": ""
        ]
    ]
```

Under "requestRequirement" section, "staffSkills" is as array. But when I am sending this to my backend, the array is splited to object means every index of the array is converted to an object.

Can any one tell me how should I solve the problem, so that I can receive the proper JSON on my backend server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tips like how you can append data for post parameters

```
  var requestRequirement : [[String : Any]]  = [[:]]
        requestRequirement.append(
            [   "state": "",
                "city" : "ff"])



        let params:[String: Any] = ["isUrgent": "1",
                                    "bestTime": "Morning",
                                    "requestType": "1",
                                    "api_key": "12345678",
                                    "userId": "37",
                                    "endTime": "1492757638",
                                    "startTime": "1492671236",
                                    "title": "Aa",
                                    "requestRequirement":requestRequirement]
```

Like that you need to follow paramter dictionary.